# onTouch method does not work

Tags: android, touch

I am using `onTouch` method for doing some works. At first step, I want to show currentX value. However, my code does not work at all. How I resolve this issue?

```
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
      int currentX = (int) event.getX();    

      if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

        Log.d("mesage:",currentX+"");

      }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: This will probably solve your problems as it explains how it works and what needs to be done : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23043320/4232337

Comment: add Log.d in the beginning of the method

Comment: Sarah, have you registered onTouchListener()???

Comment: @pskink i want when user touch screen and fingers go to the right side , a message show to him for example. Therefore must be do this work in if statement not in begining.

Comment: no @pratt. what do i do?

Comment: @sarah on which component you want to touch? like, button, ImageView etc??

Comment: @pratt on the screen.

Comment: @sarah its okay, post your whole class code, let me give you idea.

Comment: My code is very simple. It has a onCreate without any code in it, just setContetentView(activity_main);

Comment: @sarah In your activity_main is there any layout declared?

Comment: @sarah Please, post the complete code of your Activity and activity_main XML.

Answer (score 0):

check out this link:
[Detecting Common Gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

You have there snippet like this:

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view); 
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // your stuff     
        return true;
    }
});
```

do you register your listener for a view? is it separated listener or implemented in Activity or other? is it MotionEventCompat or built in? we need more code...

but you said that you need to recognize "fingers to the right side". look in my link for gestures and "Detecting All Supported Gestures" or "Detecting a Subset of Supported Gestures". onFling method is what you want (right/left you can regonize by velocityX>0 or <0)

edit:
in your activity_main you should have more views. you also may set id for main viewGroup (LinearLayout/RelativeLayout?), which is in whole Activity (Screen) and get this view in findViewById, then setOnTouchLister for this particular view. but like I said above probably you need Gesture

Comment: your file is forbidden on net. can u give me true link?

Comment: developer android com /training/gestures/detector html

or just put in Google "Detecting Common Gestures"

for me link is working...